# for loop with conditions only on every 5th iteration

Tags: r, nested

I am trying to create a for loop that updates a matrix for ever iteration, but I would like it to do something different every 5th iteration. How can I achieve this without making multiple if statements. Basically, how do I simplify to include a for loop that only applies every 5th iteration.

Here is my code:

```
NCols=5
NRows=5 
mymat<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
matlist <- list()
matlist[[1]] <- mymat

days <- 50

for (i in 2:days){
        matlist[[i]] <- matlist[[i-1]]*2
        if (i == 5){
                matlist[[i]][2,2] <- matlist[[i]][2,2]+1
          }
}
```

Comment: How about `if (i %% 5 == 0)`?

Comment: Are you aware that `for (i in 2:days){ matlist[[i]] <- matlist[[i-1]]*2 ...etc...}` computes an exponential?

Comment: @RuiBarradas yes, I tried to give a simple example. This is not an actual calculation. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you @ytu. If you want, please use your comment as an answer!

Comment: I just posted my answer below. Please take a look and consider accepting it if that suffices your need. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the `if` statement as: whenever the remainder of i divided by 5 is equal to 0.

Substitute `if (i %% 5 == 0)` for `if (i == 5)` in your codes will work.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop seems to start from 2 so the first fifth iteration will be when i=6.So, based on that the code would be :-

```
NCols=5
NRows=5 
mymat<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
matlist <- list()
matlist[[1]] <- mymat

days <- 50

for (i in 2:days){
        matlist[[i]] <- matlist[[i-1]]*2
        if (i-1 %% 5 == 0){
                matlist[[i]][2,2] <- matlist[[i]][2,2]+1
        }
}
```

But if you want it for i = 5, 10, 15 ....n so on then :-

```
NCols=5
NRows=5 
mymat<-matrix(runif(NCols*NRows), ncol=NCols) 
matlist <- list()
matlist[[1]] <- mymat

days <- 50

for (i in 2:days){
        matlist[[i]] <- matlist[[i-1]]*2
        if (i %% 5 == 0){
                matlist[[i]][2,2] <- matlist[[i]][2,2]+1
        }
}
```